# Start Connection JMS?

Tags: java, jms, producer-consumer, hornetq

I am trying to build a basic Producer Consumer application. I have three queues for message processing and can have multiple producers and consumers. The basic problem that I am facing here is that when should I call the

```
connection.start()
```

method of the javax.jms.QueueConnection that I am using. All the examples listed online ( eg :- https://github.com/hornetq/hornetq/blob/master/examples/jms/jmx/src/main/java/org/hornetq/jms/example/JMXExample.java)
show that after we have produced a message on a destination and after we have started a consumer should we start the connection. i.e. The `connection.start()` is usually the last thing to do. Is it possible that I could start my connection as and when it is created ? For example, something like this

```
Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
jndiProps.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
jndiProps.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
jndiProps.put("java.naming.provider.url", "localhost:1099");
context = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
QueueConnectionFactory factory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup("/ConnectionFactory");
connection = factory.createQueueConnection();
connection.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you using asynchronous consumer i.e. do you have `onMessage` method to receive messages?

The reason for calling `connection.start` after consumers have been created is that `connection.start` call tells the messaging provider to start message delivery. Your application must be ready to receive messages. If you are using a message listener (`onMessage` method), then it is recommended you create the consumer first, setup message listener and then call `connection.start` so that your application is ready to receive messages.

Otherwise you can call `connection.start` and then call `consumer.receive` method to receive messages synchronously.

Note if your application is producing messages and does not have a consumer, then there is no need to call `connection.start`.